# How to play sound from string array using fragments (android)

Tags: android, eclipse, android-fragmentactivity, android-button, android-listfragment

If anyone could assist me with this little hiccup i'm having i would be grateful. Thanks in advance.

I have an app structure made from fragments and activities...

The main fragment is called "Headlines" - this displays to the user a list of words in a clickable list.

The detail view page for that is called "Articles" and the activity holding the data which is a list of words is called "Greetings".

Pretty much - in the articles activity;
I have: a List of words, the translated form of the words, synonyms etc and they are all stored using string arrays.

Once a word is selected, it launches the "details activity page" displaying more information on the selected word.

I want to be able to input a sound button here that allows the user to hear the translated word when pressed.

Note:
I have already placed the image button in the xml file for the final output, so it is viewable on whenever a user selects a word. I just need to program the button to be functional now.

The code below is where i have the list of words stored:
                package com.example.sample;

```
            public class GreetingsWords {
            static String[] Headlines = {
            "Hello",
            "Goodbye",
            "Good Morning",
            "Good Night",
            };
             static String[] Articles = {
            //word 1
            "'Hello'    \n\n\n " +
            "Translation:   Yow! \n\n" +

            "Pronouncation:  [Yoh'ow] \n\n" +
            "Synonyms:  Greetings!, Hello!, Hi, Hey \n\n",

             //word 2       
            "'GoodBye'  \n\n\n " +
            "Translation:   Lata \n\n" +
            "Pronouncation: [lay'ta] \n\n\n" +  

            "Synonym:   Likkle More. \n\n" +
            "Pronouncation: [lickle- mor']",

            //word 3
            "'Good Morning' \n\n\n " +
            "Translation:   Mawnin \n\n" +
            "Pronouncation: [Maw-ning] ",       

            //word 4
            "'Good Night' \n\n\n " +
            "Translation:   Nighty Nights \n\n",      
            };
            }
```